# How many bytes uses stack with N items?

Tags: java, c#, performance, memory-management

I would like to analyze space performance and I have the following code:

```
public class ListStack<T> : IStack<T>
{
    private class Node
    {
        public Node next;
        public T value;
    }
    private string[] arr;
    private Node last;
    private int size;
    ....
}
```

How much space does it use?

I know that in Java this code will have:

`16 bytes` (object overhead)

`8 bytes` (inner class extra overhead)

`8 bytes` (reference to String)

`8 bytes` (reference to Node)

`8 bytes` (reference to array)

`24 bytes`(array overhead)

...

But what about C# (including padding, array overhead, etc.)? C# use the same amount of space like Java? If not, what the difference between them?

Comment: Empty? Or with n objects chained?

Comment: Empty and with n objects

Comment: Isnt this a linked list?

Comment: [Here](http://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2011/04/05/of-memory-and-strings/) there is an article of Jon Skeet on memory benchmarking... There are even pre-calculated occupations of objects.